# R writing binary data

Tags: r

I have three big vectors with the same dimension. I need to write them in a binary file with a certain order: two integers followed by a double.
Example:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4) #integers
b <- c(5,6,7,8) #integers
d <- c(1.32421, 1.42342134123,21.4123412361,1.123412346) #doubles
# desired order:
# 1, 5, 1.32421, 2, 6, 1.42342134123, 3, 7, 21.4123412361, 4, 8, 1.12344112346
```

I would like doing it witout using a loop. Is it possible?
This is my actual code for this example:

```
con_ <- "a"
file.create(con_)
con <- file(con_,"wb")
for(i in seq(1,length(a))){
  ve <- c(a[i],b[i])
  writeBin(ve,con, size = 4)
  writeBin(d[i],con, size = 8)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `rbind` the vectors to get the vectors in the desired order.

```
c(rbind(a, b, d))
#Similar to
#c(t(cbind(a, b, d)))

#[1]  1.00  5.00  1.32  2.00  6.00  1.42  3.00  7.00 21.41  4.00  8.00  1.12
```

Note that you can have data of only one class in a vector. So in this example, all of them turn into numeric.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `order` and it should also work when the lengths are not the same

```
c(a, b, d)[order(c(seq_along(a), seq_along(b), seq_along(d)))]
#[1]  1.000000  5.000000  1.324210  2.000000  6.000000  1.423421  3.000000  7.000000 21.412341  4.000000  8.000000  1.123412
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make 1 vector from those 3:

```
list(a, b, d) %>% 
  purrr::transpose() %>%
  unlist()
```

but then that vector will be numeric:

```
[1]  1.000000  5.000000  1.324210  2.000000  6.000000  1.423421  3.000000  7.000000
[9] 21.412341  4.000000  8.000000  1.123412
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the job of `spintf`:

```
decimals <- nchar(d) - nchar(floor(d)) - 1

sprintf(paste0("%i, %i, ", "%.", decimals, "f"), a, b, d)

[1] "1, 5, 1.32421"       "2, 6, 1.42342134123" "3, 7, 21.4123412361"
[4] "4, 8, 1.123412346"
```

If you need the result as a vector of length = length(a) + length(b) + length(d):

```
unlist(strsplit(sprintf(paste0("%i,%i,", "%.", decimals, "f"), a, b, d), ","))
 [1] "1"             "5"             "1.32421"       "2"            
 [5] "6"             "1.42342134123" "3"             "7"            
 [9] "21.4123412361" "4"             "8"             "1.123412346"
```

You can use `"%s"` (i.e. `sprint("%s, %s, %s", a, b, d)`) instead of `"%i"` and `"%f"` if you treat the elements as character.